# LastModified header doesn't appear

Tags: http, go

```
ctx.Response.Header.SetLastModified(changed)
if ctx.IfModifiedSince(changed) {
    buf = data
} else {
    ctx.SetStatusCode(fasthttp.StatusNotModified)
}
```

`ctx` is `*fasthttp.RequestCtx`.

I need a `Last-Modified` header in my response but I have only:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
```

***What am i doing wrong?***

Comment: Show a more complete example. What you pasted so far looks good.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve